# Backbone router and Meteor user authentication

Tags: meteor

I'm new to Meteor, and I would like to use a Backbone router in my project:

```
AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend
({

    "routes":
    {
        "": "home",
        // ...
    },

    "home": function()
    {
        if (Meteor.user())
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

});
```

The problem I have is that, when a user is already logged in and goes to the "home" page, Meteor.user() returns null and Meteor.loggingIn() returns true...So I guess I need to wait for the end of the authentication, but how can I do that (Meteor.loginWithPassword seems to be called automatically when loading the page)?

Answer (score 0):

assuming meteor calls some kind of callback when login finishes, delay calling `Backbone.history.start()` until then.